# Using Ansible per directory instead of per host

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I know it will sound a bit strange but I wonder if there is a way to use Ansible per directory instead of per host.

Our current use case is the following: the same application (here WordPress) is deployed into multiple folders onto the same host (probably a very common scenario at a hosting provider).

We want to manage the configuration of all the instances in a 'smart' way (hence the idea of using Ansible). for instance, the same file (plugin) should be copied into the same subfolders of the instances.

This could be very easily achieved if all instances were hosted on different hosts, but I can find a way to achieve this in different folders on the same host.

Is that completely stupid? Is there a better tool to do that? Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define different host aliases for the same physical host (or VM) like this:

hosts:

```
host_user1 ansible_host=host1.example.com app_root_path=/apps/user_john
host_user2 ansible_host=host1.example.com app_root_path=/apps/user_peter
host_user3 ansible_host=host2.example.com app_root_path=/apps/user_smith
```

this way you will have three "hosts", but `host_user1` and `host_user2` is the same physical host `host1.example.com`, whereas `host_user3` is actually `host2.example.com`. Variable `app_root_path` is specific for every host. So you can do something like this in your playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - unarchive:
        src: myapp_dist.tgz
        dest: "{{ app_root_path }}/myapp/"
```

This will extract `myapp_dist.tgz` to three different directories.

But be aware that with this approach you can have troubles with modules that require exclusive locks per host (like `apt`).

Answer (score 0):

you can define a list variable for all the folders you like to deploy your application and use the `{{ item }}` place holder for the path, so for example if you like to manage the `wp-config.php` file for all the sites,

```
- name: Manage wp-config based on a template
  template:
    src: "wp-config.php.j2"
    dest: "/sites/{{ item }}/wp-config.php"
  with_items: 
    - www.xyz.com
    - foo.bar
```